# Грамматические основы предложений

Tags: синтаксис

Разве это черви? Возможно, это черви?
Это тоже искусство. Это искусство. Да?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подлежащее - это, сказуемое - черви. Это - подлежащее, искусство - сказуемое.

Comment: И еще одна грамматическая основа - "да"

Comment: Виктор, а разве ''да''? входит, так сказать, в примеры, где необходимо найти грамматическую основу? Мне кажется, ''да'' здесь не относится к примерам, а относится к словам автора.

Comment: Да? Это мой вопрос: "это искусство" - грамматическая основа предложения?

Comment: Верьте глазам своим: слово-предложение "да" стоит последним в перечне предложений, где надо найти грамматические основы.

Comment: Серж, большое спасибо за помощь.